# Manual install of curl can't find openssl

Tags: centos, curl, openssl

My system (Centos7) install of curl doesn't support https. So I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782556/how-do-i-get-curl-to-use-https) downloaded from [source](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and [installed myself](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html), using the `./configure --with-ssl` option.

I got the following warning while configuring:

```
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl and -lpthread... no
checking for ssl_version in -laxtls... no
configure: WARNING: SSL disabled, you will not be able to use HTTPS, FTPS, NTLM and more.
configure: WARNING: Use --with-ssl, --with-gnutls, --with-polarssl, --with-cyassl, --with-nss, --with-axtls, --with-winssl, or --with-darwinssl to address this.
```

As a result, my curl build does not support https.

Open SSL is installed on my system:

```
[user@server curl-7.61.0]$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

How can I get my curl install to find openssl and support HTTPS?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't support https? The standard CentOS 7 curl package does support https and /usr/bin/curl is linked with libssl.so

Comment: @DougO'Neal When i did `curl -V` is didn't list https as supported. More precisely, git won't push or pull because `Protocol https not supported                                                 or disabled in libcurl`

Comment: First, curl and libcurl are separate packages. Second, the CentOS libcurl is also linked with libssl3.so. `curl -V` should return `curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.28.4 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3` along with Protocols and Features that include https and SSL. can you provide the output of `which curl` and `locate libcurl`?

Comment: So I have two curls on the system now, one at /usr/bin/ and one at /usr/local/bin, and there are libcurl.so files for each. I think I have this solved, I just need to get down to only one curl on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To satisfy the `configure` script and have your compiled `curl` support OpenSSL, you'll need to install the corresponding development package, `openssl-devel`.